# PowerBi timeseries duration

Tags: powerbi, dax

In PowerBI, I have a simple table with 3 columns:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("TYzBCcAwDAN38dugyk5bdxaT/deICzXN77hDyhSKCkHYwafwbJyaYiUc9I4XaH/1MgHeXQO+bcf7ux0XW3x5Lg==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [id = _t, start = _t, end = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"start", type date}, {"end", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

From which I can create the following visual

[image: TimeLine]
My challenge is to calculate the total duration in days of the times series based on filter selected above. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried the following DAX formula but it gives me crazy results as shown above.

```
YTDDuration = 
var start_Date=FIRSTDATE(ALLSELECTED('CALENDAR'[Date]))
var end_Date=LASTDATE(ALLSELECTED('CALENDAR'[Date]))
var current_Start=MAX(Table2[start])
var current_end=MAX(Table2[end])
var bigif=IF(current_end>start_Date&&current_Start<end_Date,DATEDIFF(MAX(start_Date,current_Start),MIN(end_Date,current_end),DAY),0)
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUMX(Table2, bigif),FILTER(ALL(Table2), Table2[start] <= max(Table2[end])))
```

Expected output would be: [image: TimeLine]

The key here is to account for gaps in dates and consolidate overlapping dates.

Comment: What results are you expecting? I'm not sure I understand what your bar chart is supposed to show.

Comment: Ideally cumulative duration by end_date or total duration by date will do. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? E.g. what value do you expect for May and why?

Comment: I have added expected output, the key here is day difference between the first date and the end date, accounting for gaps in dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through your calendar table and count the number of days where that day falls into one of the `id` time periods.

```
YTDDuration = 
var current_Start = CALCULATE(MIN(Table2[start]), ALL(Table2))
var current_end = MAX(Table2[end])
RETURN
    SUMX(
        FILTER('CALENDAR', 'CALENDAR'[Date] <= current_end),
        MAXX(ALL(Table2), IF([Date] > [start] && [Date] <= [end], 1, 0))
    )
```

This starts at the minimal `start` date and adds 1 for each day where that `Date` is between `start` and `end` for some row in `Table2`. If none of the rows contains that `Date`, the max is over just zeros and returns zero. If one or more matches, you get a max of one and we count that day.

---

`YTD Duration` by `end`:

[image: YTD Duration]

Comment: It works fine for the entire series, the problem occurs when I filter to a specific record, then the duration is from the start of id 1. :(

Comment: Change `ALL(Table2)` in the first line to `ALLSELECTED(Table2)`.

Comment: Changing both ALL(Table2) -> ALLSELECTED(Table2) does it. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @AlexisOlson  when is your book coming out?

Comment: @StelioK Ha. No book planned, but I'd recommend The Definitive Guide to DAX if you're looking for reading material.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Thanks man! I actually bought it a while ago, just haven't had time to get started on it. Have a nice weekend man!

Comment: @StelioK It's a long book. Be sure to at least get through chapters 4 and 5. Those are key.